# Redis crashing and not sure why

Tags: memory, redis, redisgraph

I'm attempting to load quite a bit of RedisGraph data using the bulk loader - something like 600k nodes and edges.

I'm hoping someone with more familiarity can help me debug this. This Redis instance is running in a kubernetes cluster.

```
=== REDIS BUG REPORT START: Cut & paste starting from here ===
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.531 # Redis 6.2.12 crashed by signal: 11, si_code: 2
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.531 # Accessing address: 0x7ff80442e000
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.531 # Crashed running the instruction at: 0x7ff811995e8e

------ STACK TRACE ------
EIP:
/opt/redis-stack/lib/redisgraph.so(+0x202e8e)[0x7ff811995e8e]

Backtrace:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14420)[0x7ff814ea0420]
/opt/redis-stack/lib/redisgraph.so(+0x202f53)[0x7ff811995f53]
(this times like 50 more)

------ INFO OUTPUT ------
# Server
redis_version:6.2.12
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:4dbc2487343b0024
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 5.15.0-1039-azure x86_64
arch_bits:64
monotonic_clock:POSIX clock_gettime
multiplexing_api:epoll
atomicvar_api:c11-builtin
gcc_version:9.4.0
process_id:9
process_supervised:no
run_id:65129b9dd608a9098c814c79a10f3624ff33a9a7
tcp_port:6379
server_time_usec:1687222392403359
uptime_in_seconds:181
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
configured_hz:10
lru_clock:9500792
executable:/opt/redis-stack/bin/redis-server
config_file:
io_threads_active:0

# Clients
connected_clients:92
cluster_connections:0
maxclients:10000
client_recent_max_input_buffer:48
client_recent_max_output_buffer:0
blocked_clients:0
tracking_clients:0
clients_in_timeout_table:0

# Memory
used_memory:687756138408
used_memory_human:640.52G
used_memory_rss:25559040
used_memory_rss_human:24.38M
used_memory_peak:687756138408
used_memory_peak_human:640.52G
used_memory_peak_perc:11965421.00%
used_memory_overhead:2897112
used_memory_startup:1014816
used_memory_dataset:687753241296
used_memory_dataset_perc:100.00%
allocator_allocated:4806736
allocator_active:5640192
allocator_resident:9175040
total_system_memory:67436023808
total_system_memory_human:62.80G
used_memory_lua:30720
used_memory_lua_human:30.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.17
allocator_frag_bytes:833456
allocator_rss_ratio:1.63
allocator_rss_bytes:3534848
rss_overhead_ratio:2.79
rss_overhead_bytes:16384000
mem_fragmentation_ratio:5.59
mem_fragmentation_bytes:20986944
mem_not_counted_for_evict:0
mem_replication_backlog:0
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:1865936
mem_aof_buffer:0
mem_allocator:jemalloc-5.1.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
lazyfreed_objects:0

# Persistence
loading:0
current_cow_size:0
current_cow_size_age:0
current_fork_perc:0.00
current_save_keys_processed:0
current_save_keys_total:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:588
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1687222211
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_last_cow_size:0
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0
module_fork_in_progress:0
module_fork_last_cow_size:0

# Stats
total_connections_received:113
total_commands_processed:1504
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
total_net_input_bytes:1360703
total_net_output_bytes:2041190
instantaneous_input_kbps:0.00
instantaneous_output_kbps:0.00
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
expired_stale_perc:0.00
expired_time_cap_reached_count:0
expire_cycle_cpu_milliseconds:7
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:550
keyspace_misses:209
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:0
total_forks:0
migrate_cached_sockets:0
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_hits:0
active_defrag_misses:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
tracking_total_keys:0
tracking_total_items:0
tracking_total_prefixes:0
unexpected_error_replies:0
total_error_replies:1
dump_payload_sanitizations:0
total_reads_processed:1447
total_writes_processed:1356
io_threaded_reads_processed:0
io_threaded_writes_processed:0

# Replication
role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_failover_state:no-failover
master_replid:b802ed5ef505783f43e9928e408aeae171e9c91a
master_replid2:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset:0
second_repl_offset:-1
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

# CPU
used_cpu_sys:0.220440
used_cpu_user:0.260930
used_cpu_sys_children:0.000000
used_cpu_user_children:0.000000
used_cpu_sys_main_thread:0.216214
used_cpu_user_main_thread:0.256754

# Modules
module:name=timeseries,ver=10810,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[handle-io-errors]
module:name=graph,ver=21010,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[ReJSON],options=[]
module:name=search,ver=20609,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[ReJSON],options=[handle-io-errors]
module:name=ReJSON,ver=20407,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[search|graph],using=[],options=[handle-io-errors]
module:name=bf,ver=20405,api=1,filters=0,usedby=[],using=[],options=[]

# Commandstats
cmdstat_type:calls=30,usec=24,usec_per_call=0.80,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_config:calls=1,usec=12,usec_per_call=12.00,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_set:calls=587,usec=7130,usec_per_call=12.15,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_ttl:calls=30,usec=15,usec_per_call=0.50,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_dbsize:calls=3,usec=6,usec_per_call=2.00,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_client:calls=4,usec=6,usec_per_call=1.50,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_graph.BULK:calls=2,usec=4096,usec_per_call=2048.00,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=1
cmdstat_info:calls=117,usec=46624,usec_per_call=398.50,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_get:calls=698,usec=1822,usec_per_call=2.61,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_module:calls=1,usec=6,usec_per_call=6.00,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_memory:calls=30,usec=33,usec_per_call=1.10,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0
cmdstat_scan:calls=1,usec=106,usec_per_call=106.00,rejected_calls=0,failed_calls=0

# Errorstats
errorstat_ERR:count=1

# Cluster
cluster_enabled:0

# Keyspace
db0:keys=192,expires=191,avg_ttl=5239346

------ CLIENT LIST OUTPUT ------
cmd=set user=default redir=-1
id=114 addr=127.0.0.1:38348 laddr=127.0.0.1:6379 fd=102 name=redisinsight-browser-a035fd7e age=40 idle=28 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20504 events=r cmd=ttl user=default redir=-1
id=116 addr=10.70.19.33:58154 laddr=10.70.19.32:6379 fd=103 name= age=40 idle=40 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 argv-mem=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=20496 events=r cmd=info user=default redir=-1
id=123 addr=10.70.19.33:56074 laddr=10.70.19.32:6379 fd=101 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=262134 argv-mem=319807 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=602495 events=r cmd=graph.BULK user=default redir=-1

------ CURRENT CLIENT INFO ------
id=123 addr=10.70.19.33:56074 laddr=10.70.19.32:6379 fd=101 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=262134 argv-mem=319807 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=602495 events=r cmd=graph.BULK user=default redir=-1
argv[0]: 'GRAPH.BULK'
argv[1]: '102-default'
argv[2]: '0'
argv[3]: '3953'
argv[4]: '0'
argv[5]: '2'
argv[6]: 'precedes'
argv[7]: 'specifiedBy'
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.601 # key '102-default' found in DB containing the following object:
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.601 # Object type: 5
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.601 # Object encoding: 0
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.601 # Object refcount: 1

------ MODULES INFO OUTPUT ------
# graph_executing commands

# search_version
search_version:2.6.9
search_redis_version:6.2.12 - oss

# search_index
search_number_of_indexes:0

# search_fields_statistics

# search_dialect_statistics
search_dialect_1:0
search_dialect_2:0
search_dialect_3:0

# search_runtime_configurations
search_concurrent_mode:OFF
search_enableGC:ON
search_minimal_term_prefix:2
search_maximal_prefix_expansions:200
search_query_timeout_ms:500
search_timeout_policy:return
search_cursor_read_size:1000
search_cursor_max_idle_time:300000
search_max_doc_table_size:1000000
search_max_search_results:10000
search_max_aggregate_results:10000
search_search_pool_size:20
search_index_pool_size:8
search_gc_scan_size:100
search_min_phonetic_term_length:3

# ReJSON_trace
ReJSON_trace:   0: redis_module::base_info_func
   1: rejson::__info_func
   2: modulesCollectInfo
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/module.c:7100:9
   3: logModulesInfo
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/debug.c:1624:22
   4: printCrashReport
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/debug.c:1896:5
   5: sigsegvHandler
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/debug.c:1878:5
   6: <unknown>
   7: 
 659: _BulkInsert_ReadProperty // this times like 600
 660: BulkInsert
 661: Graph_BulkInsert
 662: RedisModuleCommandDispatcher
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/module.c:695:5
 663: call
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/server.c:3750:5
 664: processCommand
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/server.c:4297:9
 665: processCommandAndResetClient
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/networking.c:2105:9
 666: processInputBuffer
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/networking.c:2206:17
 667: callHandler
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/connhelpers.h:79:18
      connSocketEventHandler
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/connection.c:295:14
 668: aeProcessEvents
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/ae.c:427:17
 669: aeMain
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/ae.c:487:9
 670: main
             at /__w/redis-stack/redis-stack/redis/src/server.c:6474:5
 671: __libc_start_main
 672: _start


------ FAST MEMORY TEST ------
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.615 # Bio thread for job type #0 terminated
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.615 # Bio thread for job type #1 terminated
9:M 20 Jun 2023 00:53:12.615 # Bio thread for job type #2 terminated
*** Preparing to test memory region 557e66f88000 (2281472 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 557e67880000 (372736 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7f03fba00000 (1005112524800 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7fee0112e000 (43003150336 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80442f000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff804c30000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff805431000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff805c32000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff8066ee000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff806eef000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80777e000 (4096 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff807780000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff807f81000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff808782000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff808f83000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff809784000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff809f85000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80a786000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80af87000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80b788000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80bf89000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80c78a000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80cf8b000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80d78c000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80df8d000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80e78e000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80ef8f000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80f790000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff80ff91000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff810792000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff810f93000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff812ec3000 (12288 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff812ec7000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff8136c8000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff8140a7000 (12288 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff8143fd000 (12288 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff814400000 (8388608 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff814c94000 (24576 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff814e88000 (16384 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff814eab000 (16384 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff815182000 (16384 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff81536e000 (8192 bytes)
*** Preparing to test memory region 7ff8153a1000 (4096 bytes)
Killed
.O.O.
```

I've tried to make sure the commands aren't hitting the size limit, 512mb, but I might be missing that mark.